# Get some objects of collection by where condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a collection with some "company" models.
My company model has the following property:

```
public virtual ICollection<Useraccount> Useraccounts { get; set; }
```

Now I'm trying to get all my companies:

```
List<Company> companies = UnitOfWork.CompanyRepository.Get().ToList();
```

This is working without problems. Now I'd like to get all Useraccounts from all companies.
How would my method call look like?

How would the code look like to get all users from all companies where id > 8?

I'm using the Unit of Work and Generic repository pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = companies.SelectMany(c => c.Useraccounts)
                      .Where(ua => ua.id > 8);
```

Or, if you mean an id of a company, then:

```
var result = companies.Where(cmp => cmp.id > 8)
                      .SelectMany(c => c.Useraccounts);
```

Comment: Thank you. 
This works really perfect:
List<Useraccount> useraccounts = UnitOfWork.CompanyRepository.Get().SelectMany(c => c.Useraccounts).Where(u => u.Id > 3).ToList();